# Como mostrar tareas obteniendo datos desde una API, con ReactJS ?.TypeError: this.state.tareas.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, api, fetch

Como pueden notar en el código que les dejo mas abajo, la petición de los datos es correcto, pero en el render hice un `console.log(this.state.tareas.results)` para verificar esto!, pero vi algo extra al momento de que esta linea es ejecutada, pues se ejecuta dos veces en la consola.

No se si es un problema de render u otra cosa por el estilo, pero por cierto les digo que el método `fetch` es correcto, pero lo raro, es que al momento de mapear el estado, este no me muestra el resultado de los datos que estoy pidiendo mostrándome este mensaje, lo que busco es poder imprimir el contenido que me aparece en el `console.log` dentro del DOM, y ahi es donde esta el problema.

[image: Error al momento de hacer Map, con javascript en React App]

**En resumen, el problema de mi aplicación ocurre cuando se empieza a leer la linea 77 del mapeo**

```
import React from 'react';
import AddTasks from './addTask';


export default class Tasks extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        ediTask: {content: '', date: ''},
        tareas: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.obtenerTareas();
  }

  obtenerTareas = () => {
    const tareas = 'https://academlo-todolist.herokuapp.com/tasks';
    fetch(tareas)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(myJson => {
            this.setState({ tareas: myJson });
            console.log(myJson);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }; 

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.tareas.results)
    return(
        <div className="todos">
            <AddTasks />
             {this.state.tareas.map((tarea, i) => {
                return (
                    <div className="card-group">
                        <div className="card mt-4 ml-2 bg-dark text-white">
                            <div className="card-body">
                                 <li key={i}>{tarea.content}</li>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}

        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas por buen camino, pero los resultados estan en `myJson.results` y tu funcion `obtenerTareas` quedaria asi:

```
obtenerTareas = () => {
    const tareas = "https://academlo-todolist.herokuapp.com/tasks";
    fetch(tareas)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(myJson => {
        this.setState({ tareas: myJson.results });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

[Aqui tienes todo el componente funcionando](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-glitter-gs9op?file=/src/App.js:267-578)

Por otra parte, el que el render se ejecute dos veces es el correcto funcionamiento de un componente en react.

Comment: Shassain, excelente muchísimas gracias por tu amable y correcta respuesta, en verdad quedo muy agradecido con tigo, me ha funcionado correctamente, no me había fijado en ese detalle tan valioso, saludos de antemano.